# Generate image byte from image Path

Tags: android, image, sqlite

I have an android application i'm developing but i have come to face the problem of converting image path into bytes.I have a C library for matching images and i want to pass image from sqlite into library so that the image can be matched with other image, Here is the code block that i receive an image path from sqlite:

```
private byte matdata[] = new byte[512];
for (Multimedia multdata : multimedialist) {
                                    String log = "Id: " + multdata.getID() + " ,FID: "
                                            + multdata.getFID() + " ,PATH: " + multdata.getPath();
                                    String imagePath = multdata.getPath();

                                    clibrary.GetTemplateByGen(matdata, matsize);
                                    mret = clibrary.MatchTemplate(refdata, refsize[0], matdata, matsize[0]);
                                    Log.i("MATCH" ,""+mret);
                                    Log.i("PATH" ,""+multdata.getPath());
                                }
```

As per code block above ,i need to to convert the value for `String imagePath` to `new byte[512]` so that i can pass it on `clibrary.GetTemplateByGen(matdata, matsize);` as `clibrary.GetTemplateByGen("BYTES PASSED AFTER IMAGEPATH CONVERTED  TO BYTES[512]", matsize);`

I have tried to convert path into bitmap and then into byte as below:

```
 Bitmap bitmap = decodeImg(imagePath, 150, 150);
 final int lnth=bitmap.getByteCount();

 ByteBuffer dst= ByteBuffer.allocate(lnth);
 bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer( dst);
 byte[] bytearray=dst.array();
}public static Bitmap decodeImg(String path, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    File file = new File(path);
    if (file.exists()) {
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);'

        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
    } else
        return null;
}`
```

but still the library can not perform matching for the byte array formed.
Can anyone assist on that as i have spent a lot of time solving the issue ,Thanks in advance

Comment: You should load a Bitmap from path, and then convert it to byte array. Which of this is a problem?

Comment: I already have the bitmap ,but the library load the image as byte[512] ,i had changed the bitmap to byte[] but still the library seem not to load the matcher

Comment: how did you convert bitmap to byte array?

Comment: `face the problem of converting image path into bytes.`. ? Strange problem description. If you have a jpg file then just send the jpg file. You indeed can first load that file in a byte array. Directly. Do not use Bitmap or BitmapFactory. What kind of 'image type' does the server expect?